# generating html from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

In my .aspx.cs I have a code that reads a  .xml file and I deserialize the xml into an object called Post. Problem is that in my .aspx page I have a div and I want to fill in the content of this div from code behind using the html generated from the code behind.. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The div you mentioned from the aspx markup:

```
<div><asp:Literal ID="PostContent" runat="server" /></div>
```

Your code behind:

```
PostContent.Text = Post.GeneratedHtml;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the InnerHtml or InnerText properties of the div to load your text. The div will be a control of type HtmlGenericControl.

In your page:

```
<div id="content" runat="server" />
```

In your codebehind:

```
protected HtmlGenericControl content;

content.InnerHtml = myGeneratedText;
```

Comment: so the name of the id of the div should match the variable name for the HtmlGenericControl?

Comment: Yes - and it must be protected (or public). If you have visual studio set up to automatically build a partial class, this will get done for you (I don't remember what this is called [web application project??] - I don't use it). Also, as Sky points out, there are other options - a Literal control is a good one. Or you can use code directly in the aspx file: <%= myGeneratedText %>.

Comment: This is good. But you will probably want to HtmlEncode myGeneratedText since it is html:

content.InnerHtml = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(myGeneratedText);

Answer (score 2):

Use a [Literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.literal.aspx) control. Example [here](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/showasp.asp?filename=demo_literal2).